# Wordpress doesn't identify <div data-iview:image

Tags: html, wordpress, slider

```
<div id="iview">
 <div data-iview:image="img/slide-1.jpg"></div>
 <div data-iview:image="img/slide-2.jpg"></div>
 <div data-iview:image="img/slide-3.jpg"></div>
 </div>
```

why this is section is not identifiable in wordpress ?? the image path is added but its not working

Comment: What do you mean identifiable in WordPress? Unless there is a script running on the client-side turning `data-iview:image` into an actual background image or image tag, it won't run. It's not valid HTML that produces an image, it's just a custom data attribute.

Comment: you will to add script
like         <script type="text/javascript" src="js/raphael-min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.js"></script>
<script src="js/iview.js"></script>

check this link https://github.com/iprodev/iView/blob/master/index.html